# How to fix opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'^?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Goal is to be able to use lbp cascade classifier for recognizing faces but facing this problem. 
h264@0x2774710 error while decoding MB 6 14, bytestream -7

This is for an opencv v3.4.4 application running on rpi3.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)

while (True):

    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret:
        # convert to gray scale of each frames
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Detects faces of different sizes in the input image
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

Expected result: grayscale frames, followed by rectangle over face.
Actual result: frozen frame after face appears.

Comment: It is not clear from your question which error (assertion in cascadedetect.cpp or h264 decoding error) is an issue in the first place. If you get the decoding error first, it seems there is something wrong in decoding your rtsp h264 stream. Still it's unclear why it leads to second error, as `VideoCapture.read` should return false in case of failure. Maybe check `img` to be not empty (have non-zero sizes) additionaly.

Comment: If the assertion failure happens first, there is an error loading the cascade most probably. Add some code where you load the cascade to check what could go wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oliort. Both were issues but I resolved the assertion issue.                      Only getting this error [h264 @ 0x14c4770] error while decoding MB 26 28, bytestream -11() exactly when a face is detected by the face_cascade.detectMultiScale function.